# React state update not working with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Okay so it's simple

I have an array of answers inside an array of questions.
the user has the option to select more than one answer.

When an answer is selected, the text should change to selected and unselected if it isn't selected.

These are the steps i've tried to update my state

## step 1 using map

```
setTestInfo((state) => {
    const allStateQuestions = state.info.questions;

    const currentQuestion = allStateQuestions.filter(
      (question) => question.id === questionId
    )[0];

    const allAnswersMap = currentQuestion.answers.map((answer) =>
      answer.id === answerId
        ? (() => {
            answer.is_chosen = !answer.is_chosen;
            return answer;
          })()
        : answer
    );
    currentQuestion.answers = allAnswersMap;

    return {
      ...state,
      info: {
        ...state.info,
        questions: allStateQuestions,
      },
    };
  });
```

## step 2 using find

```
setTestInfo((state) => {
    const allStateQuestions = state.info.questions;

    const currentQuestion = allStateQuestions.filter(
      (question) => question.id === questionId
    )[0];

    const currentAnswer = currentQuestion.answers.find(
      (answer) => answer.id === parseInt(answerId)
    );
     
    currentAnswer.is_chosen = !currentAnswer.is_chosen;

    // i even went to the extend of reassigning it yet it doesn't work
    currentQuestion.answers.filter((answer) => answer.id === answerId)[0] =
      currentAnswer;

    return {
      ...state,
      info: {
        ...state.info,

        questions: allStateQuestions,
      },
    };
  });
```

Well after using the sample logics above, none of them seem to work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the state in both cases. I'll cover the first snippet.

```
setTestInfo((state) => {
  const allStateQuestions = state.info.questions; // <-- reference to state

  const currentQuestion = allStateQuestions.filter( // <-- reference to state
    (question) => question.id === questionId
  )[0];

  const allAnswersMap = currentQuestion.answers.map((answer) =>
    answer.id === answerId
      ? (() => {
          answer.is_chosen = !answer.is_chosen; // <-- state mutation!!
          return answer;
        })()
      : answer
  );
  currentQuestion.answers = allAnswersMap; // <-- state mutation!!

  return {
    ...state,
    info: {
      ...state.info,
      questions: allStateQuestions, // <-- saved reference back into state
    },
  };
});
```

The `currentQuestion.answers` object of the `state.info.questions` state was mutated and the `state.info.questions` array reference never changed so React isn't "seeing" this as an update and isn't triggering a rerender.

## Solution

Apply the immutable update pattern. You must shallow copy all updates into ***new*** array and object references.

```
setTestInfo((state) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    info: {
      ...state.info,
      // new questions array
      questions: state.info.questions.map(question => question.id === questionId
        ? { // new question object
          ...question,
          // new answers array
          answers: question.answers.map(answer => answer.id === answerId
            ? { // new answer object
              ...answer,
              is_chosen: !answer.is_chosen,
            }
            : answer
          ),
        }
        : question
      ),
    },
  };
});
```